# How to get location.state in svelte-sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a route pet/id and I'm trying to get the id and fetch my API with it to get information for an individual pet. How can I achieve that?

I've seen the preload function in the Sapper documentation but clearly this is not the proper way to achieve my goal because I get undefined when I'm trying to print a property of my pet object.

```js
     <script context="module">
       export async function preload(page, session) {
         const { id } = page.params;

         const res = await 
         this.fetch(`http://localhost/api/public/api/pets/${id}`);
         const pet = await res.json();

         return { pet };
       }

    <svelte:head>
       <title>{pet.name}</title>
    </svelte:head>

    <h1>{pet.name}</h1> // Undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Since the function is asynchronous it needs some time to complete but I was trying to print the pet name immediately. What I did to fix it is:

```js
    {#if pet} // Proceed to print the name when there is a pet
      <h1>{pet[0].name}</h1>
    {:else}
      <h4>Loading...</h4> // Show a loading message while the function is executing
    {/if}
```